# update time only in sql server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime, time

I want to **`UPDATE`** my **`DateTime`** Column but only time can be updated.

for example I have a dateTime column value: `2014-11-27 09:33:57.000` to `2014-11-27 09:45:00.000`.

Here's my code so far:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET MyDate = DATEADD(HOUR, 4, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(MyDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))
```

but the sql code above it only `ADD HOURS`.. I want also to edit the minutes:*(so i tried this but it gives me no luck)*:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET MyDate = DATEADD(HOUR, 9.45, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(MyDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the various parts of date/time by nesting the `dateadd` function calls, like so:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET MyDate = DATEADD(MINUTE,45,DATEADD(HOUR, 9, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(MyDate AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)))
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/WQKED16228)

Comment: ohh. ok. So I must breakdown first the time.. I thought there is also a SQL function for that. Anyways thank you!